# Fault Recovery of a UAV using MATLAB

Tags: control-engineering, dynamics, matlab, transfer-function

I'm currently investigating fault recovery in a UAV using MATLAB.

*I've been given several variables:*

- **phi** = the roll angle
- **psi** = the yaw/heading angle
- **beta** = the side slip
- **p** = roll rate
- **r** = yaw/heading rate
- **delta_r** = angle of the rudder
- **delta_a** = angle of the aileron (the aileron is currently inactive).

**My input is the rudder angle.**

**I've simulated a step fault in the yaw/heading sensor and I'm trying to recover from it.**

*To detect that there was a fault in the heading sensors:* I compared the actual side-slip with the modeled side slip. If there is a difference between the "real' system and the model in heading angle, but no difference in side-slip, then the heading sensor is faulty.

*To recover from this fault:* I want to reconfigure the side-slip so I can use it to determine the heading/yaw angle. In order to do this I need to multiply the side-slip by the transfer function between side-slip and heading/yaw angle.

**We've been given the following equations:**

[image]

**I'm having some trouble coming up with a transfer function between side slip and heading angle.**

*I figured the best thing to do, as I am using a simulation filled with arrays, is to turn all the derivatives into their discrete equivalent* - of course this is means I'm not using a transfer function, but an equation. Taking the equation for the derivative of beta and discretizing it...

[image]

**When I plug this in, the system doesn't recover.**

**I even tried doing Laplace transforms**, *but I get stuck here:*

[image]

**And I'm not sure how I could apply that in MATLAB**

*Is there a mistake in my logic or approach?* *How would I turn the discrete system into a transfer function?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the transfer function $\delta_r(t)\to \psi (t)$ and $\delta _r(t)\to \beta (t)$. Divide the first transfer function by the second to get the transfer function $\beta (t)\to \psi (t)$.

These calculations can be tedious. I used Mathematica to get the following result.

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel[{p'[t] == -11.450 p[t] + 2.7185 r[t] - 
      19.4399 \[Beta][t] + 78.4002 Subscript[\[Delta], a][t] - 
      2.7282 Subscript[\[Delta], r][t], 
    r'[t] == 
     0.5068 p[t] - 2.9875 r[t] + 23.3434 \[Beta][t] - 
      3.469 Subscript[\[Delta], a][t] + 
      13.9685 Subscript[\[Delta], r][t], \[Beta]'[t] == 
     0.0922 p[t] - 0.9957 r[t] - 0.4680 \[Beta][t] + 
      0.3256 \[Phi][t], \[Phi]'[t] == 
     p[t] + 0.0926 r[t], \[Psi]'[t] == r[t]}, {p[t], 
    r[t], \[Beta][t], \[Phi][t], \[Psi][t]}, {Subscript[\[Delta], r][
     t]}, {\[Psi][t], \[Beta][t]}, t];
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[
  Simplify[Divide @@ Flatten[TransferFunctionModel[ssm, s][s]]], s]
```

$$\frac{0.986478 s^3+11.6592 s^2+6.59389 s+4.77963}{-1. s^3-10.9882 s^2+1.02337 s}$$

The transfer function is unstable (assuming I did not make any typos).

```
TransferFunctionPoles[tfm]
```

> {{{-11.0805, 0, 0.0923575}}}

However, the transfer function from $\psi (t)\to \beta (t)$ is stable

$$ \frac{-1.01371 s^3-11.1388 s^2+1.0374 s}{s^3+11.819 s^2+6.68427 s+4.84515}$$

and we can plot its step response.

```
Plot[Evaluate@OutputResponse[tfm, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 20}], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The symbolic toolbox from MatLab can do some of that.  As can sympy or sagenb, with some coaxing.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you construct a state-space model from the given equations (which happen to be in the appropriate form) and either continue using the state space model or convert it to a transfer function in matlab.

A continuous-time state-space model looks like this:
$$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$$
$$y = Cx+Du$$
Where $x$ and $u$ are vectors and $A$ and $B$ matrices.
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \\ \vdots \\ \dot{x}_n\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix} + B\begin{bmatrix}u_1 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_m\end{bmatrix}$$

So, first determine your inputs, these are external inputs. Usually the ones you control, in your case $\delta_r$ and $\delta_a$. The states of the system (denoted with $x$) represent the system dynamics. A state-space equation always expresses a single time-derivative as a linear sum of the states and inputs. In your case these are: $p, \phi, \psi, \beta$ and $r$.
The output of the system, denoted with $y$ represents the things you measure. If you measure every state, $C$ is just an identity matrix. $D$ is a feed through matrix and is usually zero. So if you have constructed the $A, B, C$ and $D$ matrix, you can use the MATLAB command `sys = ss(A,B,C,D)` to construct the system. Although this system object is different to that constructed using `tf(den, num)`, it can be used just like one.

To convert the system to discrete time, use `sysD = c2d(sys, Ts, 'zoh');`. Here 'zoh' is the discretization method (zero-order hold), c2d supports multiple methods.

To convert the system to a transfer function matrix, use `sysTF = ss2tf(A,B,C,D);`.

EDIT: To answer your question, you must modify the state-space matrix such that $\beta$ is an input. While this might sound easy, it requires quite some rewriting. What I would attempt is to merge 2 states so one state becomes $\beta + \alpha r$. Where $\alpha$ is some constant. Its derivative will simply be $\frac{d\beta}{dt} + \alpha \frac{dr}{dt}$. To ''fix'' the error caused by this change, you add $\beta$ as a new input. So the state equation of $\psi$ becomes:
$$\frac{d\psi}{dt} = \frac{1}{\alpha}(\beta + \alpha r) - \frac{1}{\alpha}\beta$$

As $\beta$ is now an input, the transfer function can be computed. For simplicity I'd suggest you make $C$ such that $\psi$ is the only output. The resulting transferfunction matrix will look something like this:
$$H(s) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\psi(s)}{\beta(s)} & \frac{\psi(s)}{\delta_a(s)} & \frac{\psi(s)}{\delta_r(s)}\end{bmatrix} $$
Now to get the transfer function from $\beta$ to $\psi$ you just have to pick the first matrix. Remember that you must describe $\beta$ as your first input in the state-space model. Otherwise it is in a different place.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Petrus! I understand that this would give me the TF for the whole system. I need to find the transfer function of \beta and \psi so I can divide one by the other. Could you give me a hint as to how I could alter this method? Should I set all other unkowns to zero? I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I have appended my answer to the post. Also, I know other's have provided you with a direct answer, so you might already have succeeded. Despite that, I think its much more valuable to know that there are plenty of tool that allow you to model a system. The beauty about State-space modeling is that unlike TF's, there are infinite ways to represent a system in State-space, and if done properly, they all return exactly the same transfer function. As such you have the full freedom to whatever you want, as long as the math checks out ;)